# Stop animation on .siblings()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, siblings

I'm creating a page when you hover a div. That div will grow in size (width) and the other divs (siblings) will be smaller in size (width).

I use a mouseenter and a mouseleave. But I can't get the .stop() function working.
When you hover one and less than a sec another one. The old one will not stop.

Live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5kyw9ya7/7/

Code:
Html:

```
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="two">2</div>
<div class="three">3</div>
<div class="four">4</div>
<div class="five">5</div>
```

Css:

```
body, html {
    margin:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div {
    float:left;
    height:100vh;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.one {
    background-color:orange;
}
.two {
    background-color:yellow;
}
.three {
    background-color:red;
}
.four {
    background-color:purple;
}
.five {
    background-color:green;
}
```

Jquery:

```
var breedte = $(window).width() / 5;
$("div").css("width", breedte);

$("div").stop()
    .mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "+=100"
    });
    $(this).siblings().animate({
        width: "-=25",
    });
    $(this).siblings().css(
        "backgroundColor", "grey");
})
    .stop().mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "-=100"
    });
    $(this).siblings().animate({
        width: "+=25"
    });
    $(this).siblings().css(
        "backgroundColor", "");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works better if you put `.stop()` in the event handlers. You should also call it as `.stop(true,true)` in order for it to finish the animation. Otherwise, the sizes get all messed up. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

```
var breedte = $(window).width() / 5;
$("div").css("width", breedte);

$("div").stop()
    .mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).stop(true,true).animate({
        width: "+=100"
    });
    $(this).siblings().stop(true,true).animate({
        width: "-=25",
    });
    $(this).siblings().css(
        "backgroundColor", "grey");
})
    .stop().mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).stop(true,true).animate({
        width: "-=100"
    });
    $(this).siblings().stop(true,true).animate({
        width: "+=25"
    });
    $(this).siblings().css(
        "backgroundColor", "");
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5kyw9ya7/10/